# SPI (3 wire) implementation using PIC

Tags: spi, rtc

I am trying to connect my PIC to RTC. The RTC I am using is [DS1302](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1302.pdf) with only one pin for both (Input and Output). I am trying to simulate it using PROTEUS. The problem I am facing is how can I connect PIC two pins i.e. SDO and SDI to one pin (I/O) of RTC?

ScreenShot is here

[image]

Edit: I Have read the datasheet of [16fxxxx](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41417B.pdf) and couldn't find the configuration for 3 wire system.

Comment: If the device is using a single pin for in and out, then it's not SPI.  You probably have a "one wire" device.  That's a totally different protocol from SPI.  Check the datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hackish, but how about connecting a resistor between the SDO pin and the junction to the SDI pin, 4k7 or so should be ok.

Then when the RTC is using the pin as an input to will read the data from SDO, when it is an output it should override the resistor and drive the SDI pin.

You will want to look carefully at the guaranteed logic levels, but you should be able to get this to work.

Comment: The I/O pin of the DS1302 is open drain and has an internal 40k pullup resistor, so for this to work you'd have to make sure SDO was high when reading data from it.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16158781/Untitled.png
The first way or the second? The first way doesn't seem correct to me because when SDO transfers a byte to RTC. That byte will be received by SDI too (same potential as I/O).
The 2nd way is convincing.

Comment: I am seeing nothing in that datasheet that makes me think open drain here, in fact if you look at the electrical specs, a logic 1 is capable of sourcing current, so it is actually a tri state output.

Comment: @Finbarr : The datasheet says, I/O has "40k Pulldown resistor to Ground"

Comment: The first way, and why does that matter? Any SPI transaction is effectively bidirectional, you just throw away the bit you don't need. Your second way gets into a logic conflict when the DS1302 tries to drive the data line.

Comment: A 40k pulldown would not be what you would expect to see on an open drain output (It would be a pull UP), it exists to make sure that these lines have a defined state when the micro is powered off. That output is almost certainly tristate.

Comment: Nouman and @DanMills sorry, you're right, it's a pulldown resistor and a tri-state output. Ignore me :)

Comment: But DO take a look at [Application Note 3449](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3449) on the Maxim site, as it shows it interfaced to an 8051 using three GPIO lines and gives you sample code to drive it.

Comment: @DanMills : I think you are right. Let me try it first.

Answer (score 1):

The SPI protocol uses separate input and output signals, which are always active (although input or output bits are often ignored).

The DS1302 uses a single I/O pins which is either input or output, depending on the type of the transaction, and where in the transaction you are. (There is no standard for this protocol.)

Plain SPI does not work. However, you can connect both SDI/SDO pins to the I/O pin as long as you ensure that only one of them is active. In other words, ensure that the SDO pin is disabled (configured as GPIO input) whenever the DS1302 is outputting something.
However, your MCU does not allow to reconfigure a single pin (SSPEN enables all three SPI pins), so you cannot use the SPI module and have to do bit-banging instead.

Comment: Thank you CL for the reply.
I was wondering how can i make SDI or SDO pin "in-active" i.e. Neither Input nor Output for certain time.

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to force the SPI interface into doing something it wasn't really designed for. I've connected this device to an H8 using three GPIO lines and manually controlling the pins and it was very straightforward.

Comment: If I make the SDO pin input while receiving the byte, then I will get the byte but while transferring, I couldn't make the SDI pin input nor output. Let say I am transferring a byte , if I make the SDI pin GPIO ouput, then it will effect the output signal of SDO too. And if i make SDI pin input, then the output signal will be received by SDI !

Comment: "And if i make SDI pin input, then the output signal will be received by SDI" - So what? That's just how SPI works. For every byte sent you receive one byte at the same time. If and while you don't expect data from the slave just ignore the received byte(s).